# What is the correct way to wire a piezzo buzzer with a potentiometer and a button?

Tags: arduino-uno, button, potentiometer, piezo

I'm working on a morse transmitter (kind-a), this how it looks like now:
[image: Arduino-button-potentiometer-piezobuzzer]

It's working, but is it correct? My piezo buzzer is 3-24V. I use the potentiometer as a volume control. The button is for transmitting morse code.

I've seen a way of wiring like this, not using any resistors, it feels wrong, is it correct?
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/3/1/0/Arduino_circuit_11_01.png

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Arduino basically as a power supply (in your wiring). The linked wiring is for PWM (analogWrite). This allows pulse output to generate tone (and volume). Here is a good [reference](http://www.varesano.net/blog/fabio/pwm-and-arduino-fading-led-and-playing-melodies-piezo-speaker).